# variable not changing c

Tags: c, variables, initialization, int

hi im a begginer c programmer and i am trying to make a filter that is supposed to change a variable depending on other variable but it does not seem to changing the variable g1 for some reason. i really aprecciate any help i can get as i am stuck here for now. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{
    int car;
    int g1;
    int g2;
    int sel1;
    unsigned int iseed = (unsigned int)time(NULL);          
    srand (iseed);
    g1 = 0;
    car = rand() % 3 + 1;
    printf("%d\n",car);

    printf("select a door beetween 1 and 3\n ");
    scanf ("%d",&sel1);
    if (sel1 < 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid selection!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (sel1 > 3)
    {
        printf("Invalid selection!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (sel1 == 1)
    {   
        if(car == 1)
        {
            g1 = 2;
            g2 = 3;
        }   
        if (car == 2);
        {
            g1 = 3;
            g2 = 1;
        }
        if (car == 3);
        {
            g1 = 2;
            g2 = 1;
        } 
    }

    if (sel1 == 2)
    {   
        if(car == 1)
        {
            g1 = 3;
            g2 = 2;
        }   
        if (car == 2);
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 3;
        }
        if (car == 3);
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 2;
        } 
    }

        if (sel1 == 3)
    {   
        if(car == 1)
        {
            g1 = 2;
            g2 = 3;
        }   
        if (car == 2);
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 3;
        }
        if (car == 3);
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 2;
        } 
    }

    printf("Behind door %d is a goat\n",g1);



    return 0;
}
```

Apperantly i do not have enough detail so ignore this im just adding some random detail. In elementary mathematics, a variable is an alphabetic character representing a number, called the value of the variable, which is either arbitrary, not fully specified, or unknown.

Comment: `if (car == 2);` : Remove `;`

Comment: Generally, debugging would be nice. Use Visual Studio, it is easy there. If you are on linux, use gdb, but that's much harder for a beginner. (Try it though.) But you can always scatter `printf`s and see the control flow in such  small piece of code. (And bluepix is right; do you understand why?)

Comment: A program is *not* a mathematical world. It has some *changing* internal state. Read about [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science))

Comment: As a matter of style: Repetitive code like this is error prone (it is usually copied and pasted, with the usual opportunities for error). When you copy and paste something, consider making it a function. That will become a reflex. If you can compute the different values (here: for g1 and g2) with a formula, then do so. If the values are less regular, store the values in arrays etc. and look them up.

Comment: BTW, compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: The [Monty Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) problem. After the first input to "select a door between 1 and 3" the test `if (sel1 < 0)` should be `if (sel1 < 1)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY et alia: Not sure this qualifies as "simple typographical error"; the semicolon mistake is easy to make for a beginner, and it's grammatical rather than orthographic. (But I know that the available closing reasons are often not a good match for questions which really *should* be closed for which this one arguably qualifies, so ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you don't specify what should happen if `sel1==0`
You spesified it for `sel1>3` and `sel1==3` and `sel1==2` and `sel1==1` and `sel1<0` but you don't specify what if `sel1==0` I think that g1 do not change if sel1 is 0 but changes otherwise
may be you should put a space when inputting sel1 like the following

```
scanf ("%d ",&sel1);
```

and remove the `;` after the conditions `if(car==2)` and `if(car==3)`

Comment: Did you read bluepix' comment? Did you understand it?

Comment: yes @PeterA.Schneider

Comment: I ask because neither the unspecified sel1==0 not a missing space in the `printf` format are the reason why the OP's program doesn't work. It's the empty if blocks.

Comment: even if (if)block is empty the value will be changed
but not in the desired way
I think he means the value stills 0

Comment: The OP says the variable didn't change, but he didn't specify the value it had but shouldn't have (my guess is that `g1`  was always 2 except for `sel1==1` when it was always 1, independent of `car`'s value).

Answer (score 1):

First, as @BLUEPIXY suggested, you should remove the `;`.

I would change the first two sel1 condition to set just one, like this:

```
if (sel1 < 1 || sel1 > 3)
    printf("Invalid selection!\n");
```

Then I would use a `switch` case and `if` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{
    int car;
    int g1;
    int g2;
    int sel1;
    unsigned int iseed = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    srand(iseed);
    g1 = 0;
    car = rand() % 3 + 1;
    printf("Car= %d\n", car);

    printf("Select a door beetween 1 and 3:\n");
    scanf("%d", &sel1);


    if (sel1 < 1 || sel1 > 3)
        printf("Invalid selection!\n");

    switch (sel1)
    {
    case 1:
        if (car == 1)
        {
            g1 = 2;
            g2 = 3;
        }
        else if (car == 2)
        {
            g1 = 3;
            g2 = 1;
        }
        else if (car == 3)
        {
            g1 = 2;
            g2 = 1;
        }

        break;

    case 2:
        if (car == 1)
        {
            g1 = 3;
            g2 = 2;
        }
        else if (car == 2)
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 3;
        }
        else if (car == 3)
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 2;
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        if (car == 1)
        {
            g1 = 2;
            g2 = 3;
        }
        else if (car == 2)
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 3;
        }
        else if (car == 3)
        {
            g1 = 1;
            g2 = 2;
        }
        break;
    }


    printf("Behind door, %d is a goat\n", g1);


    getchar();
    getchar();  

    return 0;   
}
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: `if (sel1 < 0 || sel1 > 3)` allows 4 possibilities when there are only three. Should be `if (sel1 < 1 || sel1 > 3)`

Comment: I have edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much Cecho this work perfectly.